# Difference between Java's Serializable and C#'s ISerializable

Tags: c#, java, serialization, translation, clone

I'm translating some Java code to C#. The Java code looks something like

```
public abstract class myClass implements Cloneable, Serializable {

//fields, constructors etc here.
//...
//...

public abstract Object clone(); //an implementation of this is eventually provided 
in a subclass

//...
//...

}
```

The clone() from the Cloneable interface was implemented and Serializable has no methods so nothing needs to be implemented from there.

In C# my class looks something like this:

```
public class myClass : ISerializable, ICloneable{

//fields, constructors etc here.
//...
//...

public abstract Object Clone ();

//...
//...
```

}

As you can see, ICloneable's method was implemented, but in C#, unlike Java's Serializable,  ISerializable interface DOES have a method, so I need to implement it. The problem is I am not sure how, since I am translating this code from Java, and this doesn't need to be done there.

Can someone please let me know how to do this in C#?

I know the missing method is GetObjectData, but I have no idea how to implement it, what to pass to it, or what should be inside it, since this is completely missing in the Java equivalent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you haved used the `Serializable` interface in Java to inform that your class can be serialized. In .Net you should use a `[Serializable]` attribute for this, `ISerializable` interface has a bit different meaning.

So in .Net your code should look like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class myClass : ICloneable
{

    //fields, constructors etc here.
    //...
    //...

    public abstract Object Clone ();

    //...
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, declaring that a class "implements Serializable" marks that class as "Serializable".  The Java interface IS the marker.

In C#, you can accomplish the equivalent by marking the class with the .Net "Serializable" attribute:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

EXAMPLE:

```
// A test object that needs to be serialized.
[Serializable()]        
public class TestSimpleObject  {

    public int member1;
    public string member2;
    public string member3;
    public double member4;

    // A field that is not serialized.
    [NonSerialized()] public string member5; 

    public TestSimpleObject() {

        member1 = 11;
        member2 = "hello";
        member3 = "hello";
        member4 = 3.14159265;
        member5 = "hello world!";
    }
```

See also:

- [Has the design of marker interfaces like Java's Serializable or Cloneable evolved in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317941/has-the-design-of-marker-interfaces-like-javas-serializable-or-cloneable-evolve)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx